# PostreSQL trigger disallow an action without exceptions

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Trying to solve a problem for a university assignment. Each row in the table has a date field, and I need to disallow deleting rows that have this field less than 5 years old. Using a trigger is required and it **must not raise exceptions**. How can I do it? I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
create or replace function no_change()
returns trigger as $no_change$
begin
  if current_timestamp - old.date <= interval '5y' then
    new = old;
  end if;
  return new;
end;
$no_change$ language plpgsql;

create trigger no_change after delete on wiz
for each row execute procedure no_change();
```

Comment: Reading the docs would be a good start [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) "The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it might as well be null. However, any of these types of triggers might still abort the entire operation by raising an error."  Use a `BEFORE` trigger.

Comment: I did read the docs and they say that there is new in delete triggers but it's just null. In any way your comment just doesn't help solve the problem.

Comment: Trying to get you to use the documentation to solve your issues is helping to solve the problem. I was just more optimistic then I should of been. In any case see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but should work.

```
create or replace function no_change()
returns trigger as $no_change$
begin
  if current_timestamp - old.date <= interval '5y' then
     RETURN NULL;
  ELSE
     RETURN OLD;
  end if;
 
end;
$no_change$ language plpgsql;

create trigger no_change BEFORE delete on wiz
for each row execute procedure no_change();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can return null to signal the trigger manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e., subsequent triggers are not fired, and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does not occur for this row).

<...>

> In the case of a before-trigger on DELETE, the returned value has no direct effect, but it has to be nonnull to allow the trigger action to proceed. Note that NEW is null in DELETE triggers, so returning that is usually not sensible. The usual idiom in DELETE triggers is to return OLD.

So just return NULL in cases the date is less then 5 days old.